# python: adding a reset function to a threaded application

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

My python code runs a function that takes a long time:

```
Navigation()
```

During this execution I'd like to have a reset button. For reset button to work, I used threading and I managed to get my code into threaded callback function with the button press. How do I terminate the `Navigation()` that is currently running and call another fresh `Navigation()` function? thanks.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to post more code so others can see what you are talking about.  For example, are you already using Thread, Thread.start(), etc... ?

Comment: I have Navigation() that runs in a while loop but each loop takes a long time. I need to terminate the function immediately in case there is a button press.

Comment: GPIO.add_event_detect(GPIO_RESET, GPIO.FALLING, callback=my_callback)

  
This is how I receive interrupt now.

Answer (score 0):

If your navigation function has a loop that it executes, you could have a check to see if an "interrupt" variable is set to True.  If so, you could have the Navigation function terminate during that check:

```
def navigation(self):
    # reset self.interrupt as appropriate
    while not self.interrupt:
        pass # Do something here
        # You will want some other exit condition as well, of course.

def button_pressed_response(self):
    self.interrupt = True
    self.navigation()
```

If you have access to a multithreaded library as you indicated, you could use a more elegant callback function and simplify the reset logic as well.

Comment: I do have a loop but each loop takes a long time to execute. I need to terminate the function immediately in case there is a button press

Answer (score 0):

This answer pretty much sums up issues and pitfalls of terminating threads:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/325528